# Given n, do we have a formula for the greatest Hook number of an n-box Young diagram?

Tags: combinatorics, symmetric-groups, young-tableaux

Obviously the least Hook number is 1, by considering boxes stacked vertically or horizontally. Is there a formula for the greatest possible Hook number ?

EDIT: The Hook number of a Young diagram is defined to be the number of standard Young tableaux whose shape is that of the Young diagram.

Comment: What is the definition of "Hook number"?

Comment: Added a definition

Answer (score 2):

Too long for a comment, but I wrote some Python code to compute the partition(s) of $n$ which attain the maximal hook number. It is brute force, so it is only feasible for sufficiently small $n$, say $n\le 50$. [Link to code.](https://tio.run/##hVVRb5swEH7Pr7ipD8DaJk1STWu09HXv216qLIpcMOAU28g2yappvz27syEQVnVIIRh/9/nzd3emfnWlVsvTKeM5SCZUnKwmgJe/qZ0UCtaw@NwN2S8cLj/1kFwbUIAow1TBYx9x0yKvYd6y0VUboVwcEd/vP6ufKppirGQuVklyBlVMPiOgZsYJJ7Syu6NwJbEJyapdqfXLTjXymRsM29xtz4FKpHwXliCOZDKhHfU8MapCaTt6gwt0wq7gK1fcMMctsKrqA0DngCFcpTrjGTALrqkrROFWM54azqxQBWiTcTNtqVhVaINyJeRGSyidq@1qNrOOpS/6wE1e6eM01XLGZvf3i7uH5cNy0pvIj97ts5WdWnRzNluMzKQI7xXCh5uE247opnsYRNH1KniVhdhriDtwyECYi2no7Uu12jcFmhM8DUSGk4Fxcla@7zXPbzwzJmakF3O2K9A0xw0G20bGG452P64xmjhogCwUvO2rISxFd5LaU7RycaIxiv6CXF8dtdHZUO4VfPMwTGDJgWab1FF2aUgRtxVXhSstvmsDaCZFRbaDPekGc50JVhgm6SXxd1lXH3DmIKhKnl/HGkDYAWmoXCL4/vQjskC1DbZkNW8ZPVY2uOmR9X6CpWkjqXjP1oveetxFgI6qZH8JkU0yKgivGKeQ2OdObLGIBDoum82envf4m1@EiLyPeoT5JV@v9OP6DBvmy0@O@/O9Pn8rkZb7JPYEoaSpa@FYirQE5hyeZx6MFU60Lc2BVQ0n5ChXeEBwpqiru9LoEiYstMraFPnmpCAbThWkTKgpUFWMPNjoeK5FQuVR0vfJW/06yAVywHqsaTKwnABfuuUuPT/LoeZCDZtRI3WYsMahtYIuXol/jID1@j/LTFk2FNgmthLW9c60Z8j4YF69X@NklCSXsPpWq9v5dvwBwbKC6AqiAA/vcKnw7Tqd/gI)

Here are the optimal partitions for $n$ between $28$ and $36$. There seems to always be exactly one or two partitions attaining the maximum. The optimal partitions are also roughly triangular, even though the triangular partition $(m,m-1,\dots,2,1)$ is itself not optimal except for small enough $m$.

```
n = 28:

# 
# 
# # 
# # # 
# # # 
# # # # 
# # # # # # 
# # # # # # # # 

n = 29:

# 
# # 
# # # 
# # # # 
# # # # # 
# # # # # # 
# # # # # # # # 

n = 30:

# 
# 
# # 
# # # 
# # # # 
# # # # # 
# # # # # # 
# # # # # # # # 

n = 31:

# 
# 
# # 
# # # 
# # # # 
# # # # # 
# # # # # # 
# # # # # # # # # 

n = 32:

# 
# 
# # 
# # # 
# # # # 
# # # # # 
# # # # # # # 
# # # # # # # # # 

n = 33:

# 
# 
# 
# # 
# # # 
# # # # 
# # # # # 
# # # # # # # 
# # # # # # # # # 

n = 34:

# 
# 
# # 
# # 
# # # 
# # # # 
# # # # # 
# # # # # # # 
# # # # # # # # # 

n = 35:

# 
# 
# # 
# # 
# # # 
# # # # 
# # # # # # 
# # # # # # # 
# # # # # # # # # 

n = 36:

# 
# 
# # 
# # # 
# # # 
# # # # 
# # # # # # 
# # # # # # # 
# # # # # # # # #
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a formula for this, but you might look through the references in the links below.  There are a few related sequences from OEIS which use the equivalent language "highest degree of an irreducible representation of symmetric group $S_n$."

The sequence of counts is given in entry [A003040](https://oeis.org/A003040). Entry [A117500](https://oeis.org/A117500) gives a choice of partition for each $n$ with the maximal number of Young tableaux; John McKay's 1976 work linked there matches what Mike Earnest found in his answer (or the conjugate partition, which clearly has the same number of tableaux).